# Functions in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to learn more about Python functions and I can't get past this road block

I'm trying to use two different functions, where each one adds a number to a file when the button gets clicked and then the final function takes in this number and reports the sum.
But I keep getting a missing required positional arguments error, I'm just starting with Python and I would appreciate any help.

```
def printB1(event, bill1):
    f = open('myfile.txt', 'a')
    f.write('$10.99\n')
    bill1 += 10.99
    return bill1

def printB2(event, bill2):
    f = open('myfile.txt', 'a')
    f.write('$3.99\n')
    bill2 += 3.99
    return bill1


def printB6(event,  bill1, bill2):
    sumTotal = (bill1 + bill2)
    f = open('myfile.txt', 'a')
    f.write(sumTotal)

b1 = Button(topFrame, text="B1", foreground="red")
b1.bind("<Button-1>", printB1)
```

Comment: Why do you have two functions defined under the same name?

Comment: you should fix your indentation and duplication first

Comment: This seems related with `tkinter` ?

Comment: You should close your files when you're finished writing to them too

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I fixed the function names.

Answer (score 2):

The last line of your code binds the left mouse button to call `printB1` when clicking `b1` (which you should do with `...foreground="red", command=printB1)`, by the way). When you click a `Button` widget in Tkinter, that calls the function you've bound to it. It doesn't add any arguments on its own (this is not true everywhere in Tkinter, e.g. clicking a `Canvas` object passes an `event` automatically). Since the specified function requires two arguments, and you didn't pass any, it gives you the error you saw. If that function expects an `event` and a `bill1`... where are they? Where do you expect them to come from? You will need to either add appropriate arguments to the `command` with a wrapper function, or remove the parameters from `printB1`.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is simply keep track of the money so that if B1 is pressed 2 times, I can calculate the sum at the end. I understand I can take the bill1 and bill2 out of the function parameters, but then I can pass the values to the final bill sum. 
Is there better logic to do this? As I understand the implementation is wrong

Comment: @user37649 - See [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Introduction_to_GUI_Programming.html) for the common way to work with data in a Tkinter app.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for TigerhawkT3. 
I'm sorry to have upset users here with a simple question, I read the article and found out that using a class with a simple if/else structure would be best suited for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the code, it appears you're using the `tkinter` GUI framework.

The specific problem you're facing is in the `bind` call - the function callback you've specified takes exactly *two* arguments (namely `event` and `bill1`), but `bind` only passes one argument to it (which is `event`). This is because `bind` *only* passes the event that's fired when you interact with the object to the function `printB1`. This is by design: if you want to access the value of attributes, as I suspect you are doing, [there are other ways to go about doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973363/how-can-i-get-a-tkinter-widget-attribute). See [this example](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) for better clarity, as well as a description of the event object's methods.

In other words, scrap the `bill1` arguments because `bind` is never going to pass that value. You're going to have to figure out how to rewrite the  code to do what you want - as it is, there are too many issues in the code here to address.